# basics in c++ compiling

Tags: c++, xcode

This is the lines used to compile a c++ programme.

```
  g++ xp_example2.cpp api/gdxco.cpp ../C/api/gdxcc.c api/optco.cpp ../C/api/optcc.c api/gamsxco.cpp ../C/api/gamsxcc.c -Iapi -I../C/api
```

However, when I use IDE Xcode, I don't know what to change so that I arrive at the exact same thing.  For example, How shall I edit my Xcode to incorporated the things like "-I" ? Thank you.

Comment: You should just read the [official GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Option-Summary.html#Option-Summary) or it's man page (`man gcc`), and then just read the excellent help that exists for Xcode. You don't show any effort doing that.

Comment: maybe this has nothing to do with c++.

Answer (score 1):

Click the project in the left sidebar and a view opens. The *Build Settings* tab is what you're looking for.

For example to edit the search paths, scroll down to (or search for) *Search Paths*.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you were compiling command-line and now in xcode, correct?

In xcode, when you drag additional sources into your project, it should automatically handle the linking for you.

Also a side note, I believe the xcode project will default now to clang rather than gcc, just a heads-up if you were unaware.